# Template deduction: porting to C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, stdbind

Following code is legal for C++14 compiler

```
// g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
// output: 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5 }, b = { 2, 5, 5, 3 }, c;

  std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(c), 
    std::bind(std::less<>(),   // this won't work in pre-C++14
      std::bind(
        std::count<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, 
          std::bind(static_cast<std::vector<int>::iterator (std::vector<int>::*)()>(&std::vector<int>::begin), &c), 
          std::bind(static_cast<std::vector<int>::iterator (std::vector<int>::*)()>(&std::vector<int>::end), &c), 
          std::placeholders::_1
      ),
      std::bind(
        std::minus<>(), // this won't work in pre-C++14
          std::bind(
            std::count<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, 
              a.begin(), 
              a.end(), 
              std::placeholders::_1
          ),
          std::bind(
            std::count<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, 
              b.begin(), 
              b.end(), 
              std::placeholders::_1
          )
      )
    )
  );

  std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

It is meant to create vector c from elements of vector a  , excluding those that match count and value of elements in vector b. E.g. if a contains three  2 and b - two of them, only one 2 would be present in c.

a) how possible to adapt this code for C++11? Intuitive leap that less<> and minus<> parameter would be ...::difference_type didn't work, compiler messages aren't helpful either

b) current version removes last matches sequence-wise. What code would remove *first* matches?

Comment: oh wow, `std::bind`. Please don't use it (in both c++11 and c++14)

Comment: instead use a lambda, but I'd say you need to rethink your algorithms as well

Comment: @Ap31 that kind of offtopic comment to a theoretical question. Oh, I know there is notion: there are now lambdas so we don't need bind. But actually lambdas and bind predate C++11 but entered standard together and latter never existed without former (due implementation). The question wasn't to refactor code

Comment: @Ap31 Why not use `std::bind`?

Comment: @Swift I agree that it could be offtopic (and sorry for that), but I believe that this is precisely the way to solve your problem. With labmda, you won't need the `std::minus<>` or `std::less<>`. Also the code will be much clearer  to read

Comment: @Ap31 that's obvious that it can be replaced with copy_if(std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(c), [=](int) { .... } ); in case of simple excluding of matching elements, less obvious solution (or actually less pretty than simple lambda) for  counting repeats, but problem of manually deducing  template parameters for backporting still exist, in various cases. less<>\minus<> in C++14 got <void> implementation in which operator() itself is a template, that's why code above works, I think. This is an artificial example that replaces code I can't provide here

Comment: @Swift I agree, `less<>`&`minus<>` have a lot of features. Features that are there to make them behave like raw `<` and `-` tokens in your code. With lambda you're able to just use the `<` and `-`, so why not do that? [here](https://ideone.com/IyR5yO), how is it not better? and it works perfectly with c++11

Comment: Now for the real offtopic, [here](https://ideone.com/EAPvS7) is how I'd implement that. Of course, if you don't need to preserve the order, then perhaps there is a better way still

Comment: The lambda function is the prettier solution, but if you do not want to rewrite your code, you can just use explicit instantiations `std::less<int>` and `std::minus<int>`.  Tested with Clang 3.8 and GCC 4.9.1.

Comment: @Ap31 actual problem I have is featuring  bind(proprietary_function , bind (less<>, bind(proprietary_function ... ), bind(proprietary_function ... ) but not in _one_ single line of code, but rather distributed among rather voluptuous template code. Re-implementing that would cause IP breach, refactoring is not going  through the code check due "reasons", instead  got stuck with  a newer compiler that got  QOI issues. Actually GCC with C++11 works with code above if I give <int> instead of <>, but Microsoft compiler doesn't.

Comment: @Henri Menke yeah, that works with GCC 4.9.. for some reason doesn't work with VC or  with a proprietary compiler based off GCC 4.7

Comment: @Ap31: `std::set_difference` might be used if original order is not required.

Comment: @Swift OK, so you're saying that while the world is preparing to transfer to C++17, you're stuck with a huge ugly codebase that you cannot refactor even a bit and instead you have to transfer it BACKWARDS to C++11 under the compilers that don't really work?

Comment: @Jarod yeah, exactly. I've said "perhaps" because I'm not sure if the sorting is worth it

Comment: @Ap31 First, problem is that C++17\C+14 implementation for platform still not stable. That's very sound assumption that  world  prepares to transfer to C++17. Even now C++11 isn't implemented everywhere. About  5/6 of  Earth population lives in counties that have C++03 or incomplete C++11 as more commonly used platform. Also, that's embedded world for you, where you should be restrained in going "forward" especially,  if target CPU exist in  amount of instances described in 4-5 digit number.

Comment: `minus<>` or `less<>` are trivially implemented in C++11. There's nothing in them that uses a C++14 feature.

Comment: @T.C. you can't write minus<> in c++11, you shoul write minus<int>

Comment: Clearly the point went flying over your head, so I'll try again: it is trivial to write a type in C++11 that has the same functionality as C++14 `minus<>` in about five lines of code. If you are having so much problems, just implement them yourself.

Comment: @T.C. yes, that is last resort that is very un-loved by code checkers. for one, it turns into heavy trail of platform-dependant header-files, with obscure(and not always working) preprocessor directives to select proper variant, or just re-implementing standard library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The real answer is to just not use `bind()`. Use a lambda:

```
std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(c), [&](int elem){
    return std::count(c.begin(), c.end(), elem) <
        std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), elem) - std::count(b.begin(), b.end(), elem);
});
```

This is *far* shorter than the solution with `std::bind()`, works in C++11, and is *far* easier to understand. And we don't have to do manual template deduction either.

We could have also written it this way:

```
std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(c), [&](int& elem){
    return std::count(&elem + 1, &a[a.size()], elem) >=
        std::count(b.begin(), b.end(), elem);
});
```

Note that I'm now taking `elem` by reference. This also makes it more easier to see how to implement your proposed extension removing the first match. That's just changing which side of `elem` in `a` we're comparing:

```
std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(c), [&](int& elem) {
    return std::count(&a[0], &elem, elem) >=
        std::count(b.begin(), b.end(), elem);
});
```

Comment: Why `&a[0]`?  Have [data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) issues?

Comment: @Yakk Shorter and more symmetrical with the other version.

Comment: yet my problem is that i cant ditch at least one upmost bind and lcc(distributed sparc compiler) and compatible with it  vc 2010 compiler does not accept less<iterator::difference_type>(), which works with fully c++11 compiler, neiither trivial implementation that would replace less<> does work

Comment: @Swift Huh? I have no idea what that meant.

Comment: voted up for alternate lambda version i didn't thought of. I suppose, the easiest part to solve second part is to get container that support front push... e.g. std::list. the question formulates so it represent real-life problem that utterly cant be solved by closure use, because if some code unavailable, some is not portable, and target platforms include a spark system , a x64 linux (where everything wirks atm) and win7 embedded with vc2010

Comment: with new compiler this works faster on SPARC than bind version. Real case required refactoring of project though.